# How to free memory used by boost::multi_index::multi_index_container?

Tags: c++, memory, free, boost-multi-index

How to free the memory used by the "person_map_t multi_indexed_persons_map"?
I cant find something about it on google.

This is my testcode:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/tag.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>

struct name {};
struct age {};

struct person
{
    std::string name_;
    int age_;

    std::string name() const
    {
        return name_;
    }

    int age() const
    {
        return age_;
    }
};

typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
    person,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<name>,
            boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<person, std::string, &person::name>
        >,
        boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<age>,
            boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<person, int, &person::age>
        >
    >
> person_map_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string userinput;

    {
        person_map_t multi_indexed_persons_map;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            person p;
            p.name_ = std::string("MyName_") + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
            p.age_ = i;
            multi_indexed_persons_map.insert(p);
        }

        std::cout << "Done inserting." << std::endl;

        std::cin >> userinput; // while this is blocking, check consumtion with: `ps u -C <binname>`
    }

    // multi_indexed_persons_map.erase(multi_indexed_persons_map.begin(), multi_indexed_persons_map.end()); /* dosnt work too ... */

    std::cout << "Memory freed?" << std::endl;
    // out of scope, memory should be freed now,
    // check again with: `ps u -C <binname>` and compare.
    std::cin >> userinput;

    return 0;
}
```

How to test:

1. Start the binary.
2. Wait till its done inserting.
3. Check memory consumption with `ps u -C <binname>`.
4. cin somthing, at least one sign.
5. Check memory consumption again with `ps u -C <binname>`.

It now should be freed some memory, right?

EDIT:

valgrind output:

```
==2314== 
==2314== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2314==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2314==   total heap usage: 400,005 allocs, 400,005 frees, 16,489,069 bytes allocated
==2314== 
==2314== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2314== 
==2314== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2314== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: Even if you free memory in the heap, the size of the heap will not go down; you won't be able to see it with your ps command

Comment: You should consider learning how to use a memory leak tool like Valgrind: http://valgrind.org/ There a number of GUI front ends for that tool: http://valgrind.org/downloads/guis.html

Comment: @Emile Cormier added valgrind output.

Comment: @Myz, this confirms that the memory is indeed being freed and that you can't rely on OS memory usage stats to check for memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should and I guess it will, although I don't know the details of multi_index_container. This is more related to the platform you use than to anything regarding boost or C++.

If you put logging in the Person's ctors and dtors you can watch whether Persons are still around, I suspect they won't.

Whether the process actually returned memory to the operating system depends on the platform, but there usually is a layer of memory management between the language itself and the operating system that can hold on to memory I believe.

Also, as Emile pointed out, stl and boost classes use allocators that are an additional layer above the runtime that can also hold on to memory.

Comment: Boost's allocator for `multi_index_container` may hold on to the block of memory for a `Person` object even after its destructor is called. On top of the operating system and the C++ runtime's heap implementation, container class allocators have their own layer of memory management.

Comment: Emile, Boost.MultiIndex does not provide any particular memory allocator, it uses by default the same std::allocator as any STL container, which is generally implemented in a straightforward manner, without memory retention or anything. So my bet is what you're observing is a runtime heap effect.

Comment: @JoaquínMLópezMuñoz, I'm surprised `std::allocator` doesn't do any tricks to optimize allocation. I never bothered to see how it was implemented.

Comment: @EmileCormier, have a look at the source code of your stdlib implementation, it's typically just a wrapper around new and delete.

Answer (score -1):

Memory freeing happens when it's out of scope and not when you use erase. To get it out of scope surround it and the code that uses it with `{ }` and after the `}` the memory will be freed.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "it". Besides, even when the entire `multi_indexed_persons_map` object goes out of scope, the memory is indeed returned back to the heap, but that does not mean that the heap will return its pages of memory back to the OS.

Comment: @Dani this is exactly what if have done in the example, but Emile Cormier is right.